# fastest way to get max value of each masked np.array for many masks?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have two numpy arrays of the same shape. One contains information that I am interested in, and the other contains a bunch of integers that can be used as mask values.

In essence, I want to loop through each unique integer to get each mask for the array, then filtered the main array using this mask and find the max value of the filtered array.

For simplicity, lets say the arrays are:

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(10000,10000)
arr2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=(10000,10000))
```

right now I'm doing this:

```
maxes = {}
ids = np.unique(arr2)
for id in ids:
    max_val = arr1[np.equal(arr2, id)].max()
    maxes[id] = max_val
```

My arrays are alot bigger and this is painfully slow, I am strugging to find a quicker way of doing this...maybe there's some kind of creative method I'm not aware of, would really appreciate any help.

EDIT

let's say the majority of arr2 is actually 0 and I dont care about the 0 id, is it possible to speed it up by dropping this entire chunk from the search??

i.e.

`arr2[:, 0:4000] = 0`

and just return the maxes for ids > 0 ??

much appreciated..

Comment: Do you have just 10 labels for your actual use-case? If so, the loop-one isn't that bad then.

Comment: no I have thousands..edited the post to make it worse :D

Comment: I added an edit, sorry to add this now after the effort but, let's say the majority of the values in arr2 are actually 0 and I dont care about  0, is there a way to speed it up by just dropping that huge chunk of the array from the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Generic bin-based reduction strategies

Listed below are few approaches to tackle such scenarios where we need to perform bin-based reduction operations. So, essentially we are given two arrays and we are required to use one as the bins and the other one for values and reduce the second one.

**Approach #1 :** One strategy would be to sort `arr1` based on `arr2`. Once we have them both sorted in that same order, we find the group start and stop indices and then with appropriate [`ufunc.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html),  we do our slice-based reduction operation. That's all there is!

Here's the implementation -

```
def binmax(bins, values, reduceat_func):
    ''' Get binned statistic from two 1D arrays '''
    sidx = bins.argsort()
    bins_sorted = bins[sidx]
    grpidx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,bins_sorted[:-1]!=bins_sorted[1:]])
    max_per_group = reduceat_func(values[sidx],grpidx)
    out = dict(zip(bins_sorted[grpidx], max_per_group))
    return out

out = binmax(arr2.ravel(), arr1.ravel(), reduceat_func=np.maximum.reduceat)
```

It's applicable across ufuncs that have their corresponding `ufunc.reduceat` methods.

**Approach #2 :** We can also leverage [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html#scipy-stats-binned-statistic) that 's basically a generic utility to do some of the common reduction operations based on binned array values -

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

def binmax_v2(bins, values, statistic):
    ''' Get binned statistic from two 1D arrays '''
    num_labels = bins.max()+1
    R = np.arange(num_labels+1)
    Mx = binned_statistic(bins, values, statistic=statistic, bins=R)[0]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(Mx))
    out  = dict(zip(idx, Mx[idx].astype(int)))
    return out

out = binmax_v2(arr2.ravel(), arr1.ravel(), statistic='max')
```

Comment: testing these now, thanks...just FYI you dont actually use bins and values consistently in both inside the functions, you are just using arr1 and arr2 because they're already defined in your workspace - but I get the point

Comment: @DerekEden Yup, was bug indeed. Fixed.

Comment: thanks alot for the answer!!...fyi original method = 180s, method1 = 24s(!), method2 = 300s XD... I added a comment above about possibly speeding it up even further?? Will repeat here -  let's say the majority of the values in arr2 are actually 0 and I dont care about  0, is there a way to speed it up by just dropping that huge chunk of the array from the search?

Comment: @DerekEden You can do : `mask = arr2!=0; 
binmax(arr2[mask], arr1[mask], reduceat_func=np.maximum.reduceat)`.

Comment: lol wow...just replacing the arr2 values with zero as shown in my edit in the OP, it went down to 14s and with using the mask down to 11s...this is an great speed up ... now to test it on my real dataset which took 50min using my initial method :D

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to beat this, but will wait out of fairness for another solution...this is lightning fast..my actual usecase went from 50min to literally a few seconds

Comment: @DerekEden Is your `arr1` just uniform random values in `[0, 1)` for your actual use-case?

Comment: no it's actually values from 0 to anywhere up to 50, but mostly between 0-2ish, kind of random but no rhyme or reason

Comment: thanks for this answer, both worked but method1 was muuuuch faster :)